# Why is the Arccosine of $30$ degrees undefined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Recently, while working on Trigonometry, a problem came up in which I was asked to evaluate the value of $\cos(\arccos(30^\circ))$, and I stated that the value of this function was $30$ degrees (because the cos and arccos cancel each other out). The answer, however, was stated to be undefined, as the value of $\arccos(30)$ was undefined. I plug this into Desmos, and Desmos seems to agree with that assertion, but then I plug it into Symbolab, and Symbolab seemed to agree with my answer.
What is the reason for this

Comment: The inverse cosine function takes a _number_ and gives the _angle_ that has that number _as_ its cosine.  There is no (real) angle with a cosine of $ \ 30 \ . $  The domain of arccosine is $ \ -1 \ \le \ x \ \le \ +1 \ \ . $

Comment: The "arc" functions eat ratios and spit out angle measures. Also, most systems use radian measure by default.

Comment: Note that $\arccos(30)$ and $\arccos(30^\circ)$ are not the same. You should input $\arccos(30^\circ)$.

Comment: That makes more sense. I don't know why I didn't think about that.

Comment: Hm.... $\arccos(cos(30^\circ)) = 30^\circ$ and $\cos(\arccos (\frac {\sqrt 3}2)) = \frac {\sqrt 3}2$.  But... as people said above you need to feed in the correct input.  Cos inputs angles and outputs numbers between -1 and 1.  So $\arccos$ must to the opposite, $\arccos$ must input numbers between -1 and 1 and output angles.

Comment: @Feng What do you mean in your comment? cosine of 30 degrees is fine, but what does arccos of 30 degrees even mean? arccos x means a choice of an angle so its cosine is x. So arccos of 30 degrees means an angle whose cosine is 30 degrees? Meaningless.

Comment: @coffeemath It is not meaningless. $30^\circ$ lies between $-1$ and $+1$, so $\arccos(30^\circ)$ is well-defined. Since the question states as “Arccosine of 30 degrees”, so I just thought that OP want to ask about “$\arccos(30^\circ)$. If I understood it wrongly, OP really should make sure what he wanted to ask, and write it in a concrete way, I mean, using mathematical symbols, not merely ambiguous descriptions.

Comment: @coffeemath So, I would answer the question in OP in this way: Arccosine 30 degrees is well-defined, and $\cos(\arccos(30^\circ))=30^\circ=\frac\pi6$. Because OP inputted $\arccos(30)$, not $\arccos(30^\circ)$ into Desmos, it said that undefinedness. Anyway, It seems strange to investigate $\arccos(\pi/6)$, but it is meaningful according to the definition.

Comment: The answer lies in the expected ranges of $arccos( )$ and $cos( )$, and it seems that you've switched both, or the question intentionally switches both to force the student to think outside the box. I've put a more detailed answer below, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be undefined, as you pointed out. The key to solving this problem is understanding the input and output of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions.

Your assumption that the $\cos()$ and $\arccos()$ functions would cancel out is incorrect for this particular case, but when used in a different order or with different input values, might hold. I'll explain this later on in my answer.

Consider the $\cos()$ function: it takes an angle as an input (in degrees or radians) and then outputs a value that ranges between $1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1$.

Consider the $\arccos()$ function: it takes a value between $[-1,+1]$ and outputs an angle in degrees or radians (based on how you set up a solver to produce the output).

Now, let's take a look at your question: $\cos(\arccos(30^\circ))$. Break this problem down, first. You need to find the inverse cosine of $30^\circ$ meaning that if I was to feed this unknown value into a regular $\cos()$ function, it would yield $30^\circ$. But this goes against the very definition of a $\cos()$ function that I've laid above. That's the whole reason $\arccos()$ cannot be defined for $30^\circ$, because it's meant to take this value as an input and can only process inputs between $[-1,+1]$. Hence, the answer is undefined.

Now, when would your assumption that the trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions cancel? This is subject to the conditions imposed on these functions, specifically the range in which their outputs and inputs are defined.

Consider, $\arccos(\cos(30^\circ))$. In this case, solving the internal parentheses yields a value of $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. If you plug this as input into the $\arccos()$ function, it yields $30^\circ$ as the answer. In this case, note how the inputs and outputs match the acceptable values that these functions can take/put out.

As for the reason why different solver engines yield different outputs, it is primarily dependent on how they are built to handle undefined answers. In some cases, they often correct user errors by switching the order of functions in a chain equation, and it is apparent that $Symbolab$ uses this implementation. However, it appears that $Desmos$ accurately represents the given equation as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, cosine and arccosine, as **functions**, have nothing to do with angles whether in degrees or radians.  Like any functions, they take a number as input and output a number.  Of course, while the domain of cosine is all real numbers, the range is from -1 to 1 so the domain of arccosine is -1 to 1 and so arccos(30) is undefined.

But that is over the real numbers.  If we extend cosine to the complex numbers, then we have $cos(x)= \frac{e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}}{2}$ and it may have values outside of -1 to 1.  For $cos(x)= 30$ we need to solve $\frac{e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}}{2}= 30$.

Then $e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}= 60$.  Let $y= e^{ix}$ so we have $y+\frac{1}{y}= 60$.  Multiply both sides by y to get $y^2+ 1= 60y$ or $y^2- 60y+ 1= 0$.  By the quadratic formula, $y= e^{ix}= \frac{60\pm \sqrt{3600- 4}}{2}= 30\pm\sqrt{899}$.  Taking the positive square root, $e^{ix}= 30+ \sqrt{899}$ is approximately 60 so ix is approximately ln(60)= 4.0943445622221006848304688130651 and x= arccos(30) is approximately -4.0943445622221006848304688130651i.

Comment: You do not have $\ln(60)$ and $\ln(30+\sqrt{899})$ matching to all the decimal places shown. Better to just enter $\ln(30+\sqrt{899})$ into whatever program calculates that super-accurate decimal representation.